# TStringList.LoadFromFile - Exceptions with Large Text Files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, filestream, readfile, tstringlist

I'm running Delphi RAD Studio XE2.

I have some very large files, each containing a large number of lines. The lines themselves are small - just 3 tab separated doubles. I want to load a file into a `TStringList` using `TStringList.LoadFromFile` but this raises an exception with large files.

For files of 2 million lines (approximately 1GB) I get the `EIntOverflow` exception. For larger files (20 million lines and approximately 10GB, for example) I get the `ERangeCheck` exception.

I have 32GB of RAM to play with and am just trying to load this file and use it quickly. What's going on here and what other options do I have? Could I use a file stream with a large buffer to load this file into a TStringList? If so could you please provide an example.

Comment: I just have to wonder, why are you loading 20 million lines of text? You may have better luck using a `TFileStream`.

Comment: Do you have an example showing how to use `TFileStream` to read lines of a text file into a `TStringList`?

Comment: I would prefer to store file's lines in a table in database. Manipulation then will be much faster than using T*List descendants. So the question is what you intend to do with the data?

Comment: Simply put, the real solution is to stop trying load the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When Delphi switched to Unicode in Delphi 2009, the `TStrings.LoadFromStream()` method (which `TStrings.LoadFromFile()` calls internally) became *very* inefficient for large streams/files.

Internally, `LoadFromStream()` reads the *entire file* into memory as a `TBytes`, then converts that to a `UnicodeString` using `TEncoding.GetString()` (which decodes the bytes into a `TCharArray`, copies that into the final `UnicodeString`, and then frees the array), then parses the `UnicodeString` (while the `TBytes` is still in memory) adding substrings into the list as needed.

So, just prior to `LoadFromStream()` exiting, there are *four* copies of the file data in memory - three copies taking up at worse `filesize * 3` bytes of memory (where each copy is using its own contiguous memory block + some MemoryMgr overhead), and one copy for the parsed substrings!  Granted, the first three copies are freed when `LoadFromStream()` actually exits. But this explains why you are getting memory errors before reaching that point - `LoadFromStream()` is trying to use 3-4 GB of memory to load a 1GB file, and the RTL's memory manger cannot handle that.

If you want to load the content of a large file into a `TStringList`, you are better off using `TStreamReader` instead of `LoadFromFile()`.  `TStreamReader` uses a buffered file I/O approach to read the file in small chunks.  Simply call its `ReadLine()` method in a loop, `Add()`'ing each line to the `TStringList`.  For example:

```
//MyStringList.LoadFromFile(filename);
Reader := TStreamReader.Create(filename, true);
try
  MyStringList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    MyStringList.Clear;
    while not Reader.EndOfStream do
      MyStringList.Add(Reader.ReadLine);
  finally
    MyStringList.EndUpdate;
  end;
finally
  Reader.Free;
end;
```

Maybe some day, `LoadFromStream()` might be re-written to use `TStreamReader` internally like this.

Comment: And if you know how many lines there are use `sl.Capacity := KnownValue;` to prevent multiple calls to ReallocMem()

Comment: `TStringList` does not call `ReallocMem()` on every `Add()`, it grows its memory in exponential capacities.

Comment: Memory is reallocated only when the current `Count` is at `Capacity` when adding a new string.  The `Capacity` grows (in items, the byte count would be `Capacity*SizeOf(TStringItem)` plus a little MemoryMgr overhead) as follows: `0,4,8,12,28,44,60,76,95,118,147,183,228,285,356,445,556,...`

Comment: Even if you don't know exactly how many list items there are/will be, **huge** performance gains can be had by pre-setting Capacity to a representatively large number (a best guess, if you can) and then setting it to the actual count when the items have finished loading to reclaim any 'waste'.  In this case, a good guesstimate at required capacity could be made given that the format of each line in the file is known (3 tab delim doubles):  capacity := file size / average line length

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for this. I'm testing it now and it solves my problem (at least for 5GB files). How can I tweak it to improve the performance? Is your solution using a default buffer size? How do I alter the buffer size? Furthermore, in some cases (not all) I know the number of lines and the format of each line.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - never said it did grow each time. It grows by 25% when it reaches capacity. Older versions used ReallocMem, newer use SetLength, but use a delta of current capacity / 4

Comment: @Trojanian: `TStreamReader` uses a 4KB buffer by default, but you can specify a different buffer size in the constructor. And there are plenty of third-party buffered I/O `TFileStream` implementations floating around.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The overloaded contstructor I need is then `System.Classes.TStreamReader.Create(const Filename: string; Encoding: TEncoding;  DetectBOM: Boolean = False; BufferSize: Integer = 1024)`. What is DetectBOM?

Comment: @GerryColl: How do I pre-set the capacity within the given answer example code?

Comment: @Trojanian: yes, that would be the constructor to use. `DetectBOM` tells the reader whether it can look at the beginning of the file to see if there is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) specifying the encoding of the data. Otherwise, you have to specify an encoding in the `Encoding` parameter. Since you are loading a text file, and `TStreamReader` (and `TStringList`) operates on Unicode strings, the reader needs to know what the file encoding is so it can decode the text to Unicode while reading.

Comment: @Trojanian: Deltics told you how to pre-set the capacity: `capacity := file size / average line length`.  For example: `MyStringList.Capacity := Reader.BaseStream.Size div AverageLineLength;` You have to provide a value for `AverageLineLength` based on what your data actually looks like.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks - very coherent. I learnt from this post. :-)

Comment: FWIW, stream reader is appallingly inefficient. Every time you consume something, the remainder of the buffer is moved down with `TStringBuilder.Remove`. This even ends up reallocating the buffer to reduce its capacity. Stream reader performance gets worse as the buffer size is increased. I cannot believe how appallingly bad the implementation is.